# CMMotionManager with multitasking

Tags: ios

I'm using `CMMotionManager` in my app so I can get the device motion info. I have these two methods:

```
- (void)startDeviceMotion { 
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = YES;
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 120.0;
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical];
}
```

Second is:

```
- (void)stopDeviceMotion {
    [motionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
    [motionManager release];
    motionManager = nil;
}
```

They're launched when the app starts and when the app finishes respectively. My problem is now multitasking. If I get my problem into background and then I bring it to foreground again, I get a message (with `NSZombie` activated) telling me that a `[CMMotionManager retain]` message is being sent to a deallocated instance.

Where could my problem be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using **[Jonathan's suggestion here](http://www.jonathanhui.com/ios-motion)**. Basically, to make sure only one instance of your  `CMMotionManager` is created, put your motionManager in `AppDelegate` and retrieve it by this method wherever you want to use your motionManager.

```
 -(CMMotionManager *)motionManager
 {
    CMMotionManager *motionManager = nil;
    id appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if ([appDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(motionManager)]) {
    motionManager = [appDelegate motionManager];
 }
 return motionManager;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It's absolutely work for me ! I have same problem . It waste many time to fix for me today. Thank you so much! :D